# How can I transfer emails from Outlook to Gmail?

Tags: gmail, outlook, gmail-archive

My fiancé's school is switching over from Outlook to Hosted Gmail as their mail provider.  My Fiancé would like to archive all her mail and export it to Gmail to retain it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail has a "[Google EMail Uploader](http://code.google.com/p/google-email-uploader/)" desktop utility that can do it for you.